# Remove excel document action pane

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop, vba

We can attach document action pane to any excel file using Developer-> expansion pack-> Microsoft action pane -> attach.

Once the excel is saved and opening it again will have previously stored excel document.

[image]

I have an Excel file (refer image) and I wish to remove(detach) document action pane using inter op programming in c#. Is it possible do so?

code snippet :

```
Application xlApp = null;
try
     {
        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        string versionNo = xlApp.Version;
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity mso = xlApp.AutomationSecurity;
        xlApp.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
        Workbook newWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

         // Here want code to detach document action pane.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = false;
```

Comment: it hides document action task pane but next time when I reopen excel file document action pane is still there. :(